# Finding the limit of a sequence $\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{2n+3}\left(\sqrt[3]{8^n+3}-\sqrt[3]{8^n-3}\right)$

Tags: limits

I have the following limit
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{2n+3}\left(\sqrt[3]{8^n+3}-\sqrt[3]{8^n-3}\right)$$

I don't know with what I should multiply the term.
I know that if I have for example
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n-1}-\sqrt{n+3} $$ one way to solve it is to multiply the term with $\frac{\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n+3}}{\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n+3}}$, but with my limit I have no idea.

Comment: Hint : This limit is quite easy to solve when you know that the limit is $16$

Comment: Hint: Let $u(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$, then, when $\epsilon\to0$, $$u(1+\epsilon)-u(1-\epsilon)\sim2u'(1)\epsilon.$$ You might want to compute $u'(1)$ and use all this for $$\epsilon=3\cdot8^{-n}.$$

Comment: **Hint** Analogous to the technique of "multiplying by the conjugate" mentioned for a difference of square roots, the identity $a^3 - b^3 = (a - b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$ suggests multiplying the top and bottom by a certain quantity that rationalizes the numerator and allows it to be simplified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$a^3-b^3
=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)
$,
$a-b
=(\sqrt[3]{a}-\sqrt[3]{b})(\sqrt[3]{a^2}+\sqrt[3]{a}\sqrt[3]{b}+\sqrt[3]{b^2})
$.

So,
multiply
$\sqrt[3]{a}-\sqrt[3]{b}
$
by
$\frac{\sqrt[3]{a^2}+\sqrt[3]{a}\sqrt[3]{b}+\sqrt[3]{b^2}}{\sqrt[3]{a^2}+\sqrt[3]{a}\sqrt[3]{b}+\sqrt[3]{b^2}}
$
and the limit should be easy.

Comment: Then please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
  &&
 \lim_{n\to \infty} 2^{2n+3} \left( \sqrt[3]{8^{n}+3}-\sqrt[3]{8^{n}-3} \right) \\
  &=&
  \lim_{n\to \infty}
  \left[
    2^{2n+3}
    \frac{(8^{n}+3)-(8^{n}-3)}
         {\sqrt[3]{(8^{n}+3)^{2}}+
          \sqrt[3]{8^{2n}-9}+
          \sqrt[3]{(8^{n}-3)^{2}}} 
  \right] \\
  &=&
  \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2^{2n+3} \times 6}
                    {\sqrt[3]{8^{2n}}+
                     \sqrt[3]{8^{2n}}+
                     \sqrt[3]{8^{2n}}} \\
  &=&
  \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2^{2n+3} \times 6}
                    {2^{2n} \times 3} \\
  &=& 16
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I've made that type of mistake, too, and then rushed to fix it.